# Azure Web aps- When scale out on Web Apps happens does it put load balancer

Tags: azure, cloud, virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service

Sorry guys if my question does not make sense. Let us say I have a website running in cloud. It is running under one instance.
I have a Scale out app service plan such that when CPU usage is more than 80% it creates one more instance. On day 3 let us say CPU usage gets to 85% and one more instance is created. My question is 
1) Is it going to put a load balancer in front of these two instances.
2) Are these two Virtual machines going to be in different fault domain?
3) when I have two instances and I deploy from Visual studio, is it going to deploy to both instances?

Comment: You tagged this for both virtual machines and azure web app service (web apps). Can you please edit your question (and tags) to clarify which you are specifically referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Is it going to put a load balancer in front of these two
>   instances.

The answer is **yes**, after you enable autoscale settings, when your service receives additional traffic, you will get more instances **without** doing anything.

> 2) Are these two Virtual machines going to be in different fault
>   domain?

When multiple Cloud Service role instances are deployed, Azure deploys these instances to **different** fault domains.

More information about cloud service instances and fault domains, please refer to this [blob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content-nlnl/blob/master/articles/resiliency/resiliency-high-availability-azure-applications.md).

> 3) when I have two instances and I deploy from Visual studio, is it
>   going to deploy to both instances?

No, after we deploy a new package, it will be applied in all instances of your WebApp.
More information about how to deploy APP to Azure app service, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy).

Answer (score 0):

1-) Yes

2-) Probably, however I can't say this with 100% sure, because WebApps are PaaS, you delegate the management to Microsoft.

3-) When you deploy a new package it will be applied in all instances of your WebApp.